# Better TypeScript inference of the return type of a function that can return multiple different objects

Tags: typescript

I have a function like this:

```
function foo() {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        return {
            a: 5
        };
    }

    return {
        b: false
    };
}
```

TypeScript infers the return type as:

```
function foo(): {
    a: number;
    b?: undefined;
} | {
    b: boolean;
    a?: undefined;
}
```

For my purposes, it would be better if instead it inferred it as:

```
function foo(): {
    a: number;
} | {
    b: boolean;
}
```

I know I could force that by manually including a return type in the definition of `foo`. But I'm asking this question because in reality I have a function with a much more complex return value, and I don't want to have to write the type of the return value manually and then keep it in sync forever.

Is there any way to get TypeScript to automatically infer the return type like I want it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely enough, if you assign the return value to a temporary variable first, the return type is what you'd expect:

```
function foo() {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        const ret = { a: 5 };
        return ret;
    } else { 
        const ret = { b: false };
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i did

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh "this is exactly" --- to be completely fair _not_ exactly. This code only allocates an object to be returned, and yours allocates both.

Comment: Crazy! Seems you don't even need to do that with both of them, just one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Narrow down and help Ts by storing the return types in a const, let.

```
function foo() {
  const isInRage = Math.random() < 0.5;
  const inRageResults = { a: 5 };
  const outOfRangeResults = { b: false };
  return isInRage ? inRageResults : outOfRangeResults;
}
```

Then you should get your narrow type of:

```
{
    a: number;
} | {
    b: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Try it and if it didn't infer what was asked, then downvote.